# Ensure two handlers complete in a particular order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

If I have two handlers attached to the same event, is there a way to ensure that one of them will always complete before the other.

Just for this example, I'm using a timeout to simulate a long operation. But could I have something like this:

```
var change_label = function () {

    var option = $(".selected_option a").text();
    $("li:first span").text(option);

};    


$("#container").on("click", "li", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".sel").children("li").removeClass("selected_option");

        self.addClass("selected_option");

    }, 1000);

});



$("#container").on("click", "li", function () {

    change_label();

});
```

and be sure that the text wouldn't be changed (by the second handler) until the class was applied by the first?

http://jsbin.com/ayihiv/1/edit

Comment: Best way to enforce order is to write your code so as to guarantee it. In your case, it would mean adding only one handler, and having that handler invoke `change_label()` at the appropriate time. But something tells me that you're going to tell me that this doesn't fully represent the actual issue.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah... I totally agree. But something like [this](http://jsbin.com/ayihiv/2/edit) works, so that might be what I do until I have time for a re-write. Do you have any other more subtle ideas? Thanks much.

Comment: Yes, you can use polling like that, but it should be a last resort. If you basically want to disable the second handler while the first one is working, then you could change your event delegation to be based on a class. The first one will be based on a class that's always there, but the second one based on a class that gets removed when the first one starts, and replaced when the first one ends.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah, that is better. I'll try that in the interim. Thanks, CT!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach you might find interesting.

jQuery's [Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) utility allows you to do some "loose coupling". In other words, you can have the setTimeout function stimulate an action or set of actions, without knowing what those actions are; they can be specified somewhere else in the code, the only requirement being that the same `Callbacks` queue is within scope of both blocks of code.

This is effectively a "pub/sub" pattern, although we are using it here to do something other than to publish and subscribe.

```
var cb = $.Callbacks('unique');

$("#container").on("click", "li", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".sel").children("li").removeClass("selected_option");
        self.addClass("selected_option");
        cb.fire(self.find("a").text());//<<<<<< stimulate any functions currently in the callbacks list cb, and pass the required text to them.
    }, 1000);
});

var change_label = function(txt) {
    $("li:first span").text(txt);
};
var log_it = function(txt) {
    console.log('Text changed to: ' + txt);
};
var alert_it = function(txt) {
    alert('Text changed to: ' + txt);
};

cb.add(change_label);
//cb.add(log_it);
//cb.add(alert_it);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/znABS/)**. Try uncommenting the last two lines and you will see that additional things happen when the 1 second delay is up.